# What is the terraform syntax to create an AWS Route53 TXT record that has a map as JSON as payload?

Tags: dns, amazon-route53, terraform

My intention is to create an AWS Route53 TXT record, that contains a JSON representation of a terraform map as payload.

I would expect the following to do the trick:

```
variable "payload" {
  type = "map"
  default = {
    foo = "bar"
    baz = "qux"
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "TXT-json" {
  zone_id = "${module.domain.I-zone_id}"
  name = "test.${module.domain.I-fqdn}"
  type = "TXT"
  ttl = "${var.ttl}"
  records = "${list(jsonencode(var.payload))}"
}
```

`terraform validate` and `terraform plan` are ok with that. `terraform apply` starts happily, but AWS reports an error:

```
* aws_route53_record.TXT-json: [ERR]: Error building changeset: InvalidChangeBatch: Invalid Resource Record: FATAL problem: InvalidCharacterString (Value should be enclosed in quotation marks) encountered with '"{"baz":"qux","foo":"bar"}"'
    status code: 400, request id: 062d4536-3ad3-11e7-af24-0fbcd067fb9e
```

Terraform version is

```
Terraform v0.9.4
```

String handling is very difficult in HCL. I found many references surrounding this issue on the 'net, but I can't seem to find the actual solution. A solution based on the workaround noted in [terraform#10048](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/10048) doesn't work. `"${list(substr(jsonencode(var.payload), 1, -1))}"` removes the starting curly brace `{`, not the first quote. That seems to be added later.

Adding quotes (as the error message from AWS suggests) doesn't help; it just adds more quotes, and there already are (the AWS error message is misleading).

Comment: Why does the variable have to be JSON? Terraform supports a list of strings for a variable which is what a route53 resource expects.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/route53_record.html#records

Answer (score 0):

The message you're getting is not generated by Terraform. It is a validation error raised by Route53. You'd get the same error if you added eg. `{"a":2,"foo":"bar"}` as value via the AWS console.

On the other hand, escaping the JSON works ie. I was able to add `"{\"a\":2,\"foo\":\"bar\"}"` as a TXT value through the AWS console.

If you're OK with that, you can perform a double `jsonencode`, meaning that you can `jsonencode` the JSON string generated by `jsonencode` such as:

```
variable "payload" {
  type = "map"
  default = {
    foo = "bar"
    baz = "qux"
  }
}

output "test" {
  value = "${jsonencode(jsonencode(var.payload))}"
}
```

which resolves to:

```
➜  ~ terraform apply

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

test = "{\"baz\":\"qux\",\"foo\":\"bar\"}"
```

(you would of course have to use the `aws_route53_record` resource instead of `output`)

Answer (score 0):

so basically this works:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "record_txt" {

      zone_id = "${data.aws_route53_zone.primary.zone_id}"
      name = "${var.my_domain}"
      type = "TXT"
      ttl = "300"
      records = ["{\\\"my_value\\\", \\\"${var.my_value}\\\"}"]

}
```

U're welcome.